# Is there a limit on the number of operation I can do in AWS Elastic Search?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elasticsearch

I am new to Elastic Search and I was wondering whether there is any limit on the number of put operations I can on Elastic Search per second. My system could make as many as 15000 put operations in a second and I was wondering if AWS's ES could fail with such a high number. Is there anyway to tune for for the same? I checked a few resources which helped tune the ES cluster but most of them were about tuning for speed. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: No there is no limit but it will depend on your configuration if it can handle this amount of put operations. You need to check 'Write thread pool' metric and consider scaling out if the queue size is constantly high.

Comment: You should use the "bulk" API rather than individual PUTs, to avoid index thrashing. One way to accomplish this is to feed the messages into a Kinesis Data Stream, then use a Kinesis Firehose to read the stream and update Elasticsearch.

Comment: I would also think about breaking messages into multiple indexes, and have many shards per index, to distribute the load. And also think about how you're going to clean up old data: unless you have infinite budget for storage, you'll have to do that someday.